# British "Packet" = American "X?"

Tags: word-request, american-english

[Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/packet) says:

packet [countable]:
1 (*British English*)   a container made of paper, plastic, or cardboard    that something is sold in
2 (*especially British English*) a small flat package that is sent by post or delivered to someone
...

So the picture bellow would be called *a packet of spaghetti* in British English, but not in American English:

[image: Packet of Spaghetti]

What is it called in America then? A *bag* of spaghetti? A *what* of spaghetti?

Comment: It is called a bag or a packet.  Why do you think **packet** is not what it's called in American English?

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. You also call [this](https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2278/5809406427_a96a21cfd5_b.jpg) a bag or packet of cookies? Or a sleeve of cookies?

Comment: @TRomano Because that's what Longman Dictionary's definition implies! And (US) OED says that a packet is a _paper_ or _cardboard_ container ... .

Comment: It is also called a **package** of spaghetti.  These terms are used rather loosely.  It isn't a **box** of spaghetti or a **container** of spaghetti.

Comment: I agree with Longman.  I don't know any Americans that would call that a packet of spaghetti.  I'd call a package or a bag, or even "a thing": The water's boiling, hand me that thing of spaghetti."  A "packet" is a smaller envelope-type container, ketchup comes in packets at McDonalds.  Some pre-made salads come with a packet of salad dressing. and boxed macaroni -and-cheese comes with a "flavor packet" that has some orange powder in it...

Comment: Here (the UK) the things in which McDs supply ketchup are either sachets or pots, depending if they are flatish and flexible (sachet) or deeper and rigid (pot)

Comment: How about "pack", as in " a pack of smokes", for example?

Comment: @JMB - I can't think of too many things I'd refer to as a "pack", though.  A "pack of cigarettes" or a "pack of gum" is idiomatic, but if somebody said "a pack of spaghetti", it would sound strange to me.

Comment: @Jim: you gotta meet some more Americans. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22packet%20of%20spaghetti%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me elaborate on the comments a bit.

If you were to show me this picture and quickly ask me what that is called, certainly the first thing I would say would be, "**package** of spaghetti."

There are other options, as you'll see from the numerous words used in the comments, but they do have slightly different connotations.

**Packet** is the next closest possible option (for the image you showed). In my opinion, however, when I think of a packet of food, I think of a small package of something small or granular. For example, a packet of sugar:
[image: Sugar packet]

You could also have a **box** of spaghetti, but not with the image that you gave. This would be a box of spaghetti:
[image: Box of spaghetti]

**Container** can really be applied to almost anything, but it's a broader term. I don't think that'd be the first word used here.

**Pack** is also possible, but I find myself using that more for processed things. In other words, I would say "a **pack** of pencils" or "a **pack** of cigarettes," but NOT "a pack of flour."

In all honesty, this really goes case by case, depending on the packaging, the item in the packaging, and sometimes even the part of the country that you're in.

Comment: I think you explained it well. Although container is really generic in AmE, the way I use it tends to be for things that have a resealable lid, like [these plastic ones](http://preview.tinyurl.com/njewfd5). Most things at the store can be called packages I think, but it gets a little tricky because this is a [bag of chips](http://tinyurl.com/ovngyj7) but this is a [package of tortillas](http://tinyurl.com/nwf2wvz) even though it's in a resealable bag.

Answer (score 8):

I can't believe I didn't notice the WORD CHOICE notes at the end of that same [Longman Dictionary webpage](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/packet):

> WORD CHOICE
>   package, packet, packaging, packing, pack
>   !! Do not confuse these similar words.
>
> A package is a parcel, usually sent by post
>   • *A package containing a bomb was delivered to her home.*
>
> In American English, a **package** is also a paper or plastic container that food etc is sold in
>   • *a package of cookies*
>
> In British English, a packet is a box, bag, or some other container that things are sold in
>   • *a packet of biscuits*
>   • *a packet of crisps.*
>
> A packet can also sometimes be called a pack
>   • *a pack of cigarettes.*
>   This meaning of **pack** is also used in American English.
>
> In American English, a **packet** is a small flat paper or plastic container for something such as tomato ketchup or sugar. The British word for this is sachet.
>
> Packaging is material that is put round things that are sold, to protect them or to encourage people to buy them
>   • *It's the same old stuff in better packaging.*
>
> Packing is material that is put around things to protect them, especially from getting damaged in the post
>   • *Carefully remove the computer from its foam packing.*

(American usages are in bold)

This is similar to TRomano's second comment and Jim's comment, and Alex's nicely elaborate answer.