# Is this a "packet" or "package of rice crackers" in British/American English?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request, american-english, british-english

[image]

I have a bag which contains smaller bags and each small bag contains 2 rice crackers as shown in the picture.

Do British people say "**a bag of rice crackers**" and "a packet of rice crackers" when referring to the big bag and the small bag respectively in the above picture?

Do American people say "**a bag of rice crackers**" and "a package of rice crackers" when referring to the big bag and the small bag respectively in the above picture?

Comment: I (British) would call the outer container a bag or packet and the individual portion a _pack of two_.

Comment: I am British. I might well call the outer container a _three-pack_ of One Ones (or 'rice crackers') and the three individual things inside _packets of One Ones_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [British "Packet" = American "X?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74065/british-packet-american-x)

Comment: @ColleenV, the picture in that question is totally different from my picture. There are hundreds of different kinds of bags in the world. How can you just show 1 example and make learners figure out the answers to every case?

Do you think language like math? Just give 1 example and automatically learners will be able to apply it well in all other cases?

For example, you just give the rule of the simple present tense and assume learners can know how to use it and close all other questions relating to the simple present tense???
 
This is so annoying.

Comment: You can call these packets in several ways, the smaller ones I would say "single (portion)/individual packets" even if each packet contains two crackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways to call these **individual packs**, here are a few descriptions that I found online:

> Have you got - mouldy jam - lumpy milk - rancid butter - suspect sauce - or want to save weight - lose weight - or go to festival - self catering - holiday - staycation - camping - or what about wedding favours - and are you looking for - **"Single Portion"** - sachets / condiments / sticks / jiggers / dips / own / mini / tiny / small / tubs / solitary / miniatures / lone / **portions** / **solo** / pots / squeezy / pouches / singular / **packets** / individual / **bags** / boxes / personal / jars / **packs** … ?

The blurb is written by a British company called [SinglePortions](https://www.singleportions.co.uk/snacks---crisps---twiglets---crackers---nuts---single-portions-181-c.asp) who seem to have [covered all their bases](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/touch-cover-all-the-bases#:%7E:text=If%20someone%20touches%20all%20the,everything%20involved%20in%20a%20situation.&text=He%20has%20managed%20to%20touch,he%20sets%20up%20a%20job.).

In the US, it appears that [**single-serving**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22single-serving%22%20crackers&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjpoLLhvrzxAhWQ-KQKHTu1BdMQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22single-serving%22%20crackers&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CaqRZYzLQWYOu5FmgAcAB4AIABVYgBxwSSAQE4mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=muLaYOnrCJDxkwW76paYDQ&bih=640&biw=1285) is frequently used, one could call each pack “a single-serving”

The larger container, which holds the single portions or servings, can be called a ***bag***, ***box*** (if it is square shaped and made from stiff cardboard), ***packet***, ***pack*** or ***package*** **of crackers**.